# EXCEL extract data from table and sort dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table listing products, date, price and quantity.
I need to extract this data and do another table for each product and their respective date, price and quantity.
I can extract the date with :

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,SMALL(IF($F$2=$A$2:$A$7,ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($F$2)+1),ROW(1:1)))
```

How do I extract the Price and Qty as well at the same time ?
And also, How would I sort the new table with the most recent date first and so on (reverse order) ?

[image]

Comment: *How do I extract the Price and Qty as well at the same time ?* Because you want to retrieve numbers, you could use SUMIFS, and your criterias would be the date and the product itself. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Comment: ok. But how about the sorting from most recent date to past dates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put your fruit data into a Table and named the table:  `Fruits`

If you have O365, you can use:

```
F4: =SORT(FILTER(Fruits[[Date]:[Qty]],Fruits[Products]=F2),1)
```

where `F2` is a cell containing the name of the Product you wish to return:

[image]

To sort the dates descending, merely use the `sort_order` argument of the `SORT` function.

```
=SORT(FILTER(Fruits[[Date]:[Qty]],Fruits[Products]=F2),1,-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron. Works perfect to extract the data, but I still need the data to be organized with the dates in reverse order. Any simple trick to do that ?

Comment: Just use the `sort_order` argument for the `SORT` function. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't realize it had it in.